# Using our mail server but transferring website using A records to multple nameservers

Tags: dns, cpanel, nameservers

Our mail server is controlled by a relative and we use cpanel for email with our domain.
The website is controlled by a company and our godaddy name servers are set to them.

however cpanel cannot authenticate my dkim and such.
So I asked them that I wanted to change the name server to me and I would use A,cname and txt records to point website to them. they have 4 different name servers.

I was going to A record our website to them using the IP's of there 4 name servers(amazon servers)and switch the name servers back to us to validate my email

However they dont seem to want to do that. 
What steps or records do I need to transfer all http and https @ and www to pass through my server and to them without messing them up

Comment: The DNS does not work like you describe. You do not forward/set individual records to some nameservers. If you are at webhoster X ask him what IP addresses (for `A`/ `AAAA` records) or names (for `CNAME` records) you need to put for you `www` entry and potentially apex (but no `CNAME` possible at apex), that is top of zone or naked domain as it is called sometimes. As long as you also have proper MX records, the above will have no impact on email deliveries.

Comment: very interesting I did just what i wanted and now everything works.
https://imgur.com/zRoHjwy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added my name server to godaddy ,converted their name servers to ip and placed em in my zone editor.
[image: converted name servers to ip and placed em in my zone editor]